# Find similar items in mysql table when values are just a bit random

Tags: php, mysql

I have database of laboratory analysis results. Due to the nature of analysis, the results a just a bit random- it is normal in real world. All result are stored in database in integers (we keep results in ppm - part per million).
The problem is, that I want to find similar (maybe same) material analysed several times.
Database looks like this:

```
id  |v1  |v2  |v3  |v4  |... |vn
----|----|----|----|----|----|----
1   |4560|5600|3333|  56|    |0
2   |4575|5583|3354|  67|    |0
3   |4565|4333|3332|  60|    |0
4   |   0|5583|3333|  60|    |0
```

Material with id 1 and 2 is same, material 3 and 4 are unique.

I want to give tolerance +-30 or something to eliminate result randomines and find same material. It could be nice, that tolerance value could be individual for each column.

To simplify. How to ask mysql to return similar integers with value +- some error value?

Comment: You'll need to be more precise about your requirement. What do you mean by a tolerance of 30 if there are more than two? Suppose A and B differ by 25, so they're within the tolerance; and B and C differ by 20, so they're within the tolerance; but A and C differ by 45, so they're not. Are A, B and C to be treated as a group?

Comment: We measure v1 at precission +-20ppm, v2 at precission +-30ppm. And maybe v4 at precission +-5ppm. If readings are in these precission range, there is high probability, that material is same or from same batch. After this, I'll have much less results to test by other means (compare full spectrum). Sometimes material looks completely different (color, etc.) but some analysis markers shows, that it is same material only after some treatment. I need to find such materials. BTW- it is industrial waste checking for metals.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't want to do this using SQL.

Essentially what you're doing is calculating the [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)) of the graph defined by your database, where two rows have an edge connecting them if they are within the tolerance you've defined.

Assuming that your dataset is small enough to fit in memory, which is likely if it's results of sample tests conducted in your laboratory, then your best bet is to read it all in and then use a suitable library to calculate the connected components. For instance, in Java, you could use [JGraphT](http://jgrapht.org/); if you need to do it in PHP then I'm sure there will be graph libraries available for that too.

At the high end, with massive datasets, there are libraries to do it on a Spark cluster...

Comment: I don't think it is external library task. All I need to find materials that fit my criteria: v1 +-30 AND v2+-20 AND... last value +-tolerance. If I have some result, I can play with tolerance to narrow or widen results. And I think it is the job for sql.

Comment: @Levas but within the tolerance of what, exactly? Which row? If there could be only two rows that were the same material, it would be easy, and you could do it in the way you suggest. But if there can be ten rows that are all from the same material, you can't do it that way, because you don't have a particular row to use as a reference point for tolerance checking. The results will depend on which one you pick. That's why you need a connected components algorithm.

Comment: each COLUMN has own tolerance. I must search all database and find similar materials.

Comment: Let's assume I've made measurements and now I have material: v1=1000+-10ppm, v2=1200+-30ppm, v3=60+-5ppm. Now I search database for records where all (v1, v2, v3) are similar to new results. This will give about 10 result from 1000'nds. I can do such search in any programming language simply by comparing all results in database. But I want't to do it in mysql itself. It will be much faster than in php. Sorry for hard explanation- English is not my native language.

Comment: @Levas yes. But which row will you use as your reference point for searching? If the first three rows are A, B and C as defined in my comment on the question, then you'll get different results depending on what order they appear in. You don't want all the rows that are within a tolerance of row *x*, because there's no sensible way of choosing *x*. You want to find disjoint sets of rows where each is within the tolerance of something else within the set; and that's a graph problem.

Comment: @Levas your examples are making the problem seem easier than it is, because you haven't considered cases like the one I mentioned, where A is close to B, and B is close to C, but A isn't close to C. As the number of elements in each connected group goes up, this will get more and more problematic.

Comment: If it very simple... check v1 for similar value. Result is array of id's. Now check this array for v2. This give even smaller array of results...

Comment: The problem is I don't know how to ask mysql for similar results.

Comment: The problem is to find red and round toys in the box. The tint of color is not interesting. The size is not interesting. And I dont like that when I press return post is sent to webpage.